# Zip a big .csv file in Unix

Tags: unix

I have .csv files ranging from 0.2 to 12 GB, is there a good way to compress and zip these files in unix. I want the file to be of the smallest size possible to make the download of the file quicker.

Comment: `man zip`: _- - -9 indicates the slowest compression speed (optimal compression, ignores the suffix list)_ Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: @JamesBrown any advanced commands apart from zip or gzip ? may be a combination of commands which would give optimal compression as well as speed?

Comment: The `.xz` and `.lz` suffixes are usually better than `.zip` or `.gz`; even `.bz2` is often better.  The `bzip2` program compresses/decompresses `.bz2` files; the `xz` program compresses/decompresses `.xz` files; the `lzip` program compresses/decompresses `.lz` files.  Ignore the `compress` and `uncompress` commands — they produce files with the `.Z` extension but the output is significantly bigger compressed files than any of the others.  The `pack` and `unpack` commands produce `.z` files that are bigger still. Both `compress`/`uncompress` and the `pack`/`unpack` are very ancient.

Comment: There's also `lzma` which compresses/decompresses files with the `.lzma` suffix.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler but does xz command takes a lot of time. I tried using the command but it takes lot of time as compared to gzip command, any suggestions here ?

Comment: Also, for some -  I have the code written in .sql file which spools the data in the .csv file, is there a command I can mention in the .sql file to zip the .csv file generated ? Looking for possibilities to avoid writing shell script to zip the output file.

Comment: Better compression requires more analysis than simpler compression — the more extreme the compression, the longer it takes.  (Decompression is usually less expensive than compression.) Whether you can compress the output from an SQL command on the fly depends on the DBMS and how the file is generated.  Some systems may allow you to avoid the intermediate, uncompressed file; others will not.

Comment: ok.Im using oracle DB and sqlplus to spool the output in the .csv file, if thats what u asking ?

Comment: Zstandard is faster than xz and at higher compression levels produces almost as compact results. `zstd -T0 --long -19 foo.csv` should give decent results with large files. `zstd -T0 --ultra --long -22 foo.csv` for maximum compression.